# glDrawPixels not working with glfw

Tags: opengl, glfw

I have been trying to draw some pixels directly using `glDrawPixels` but cannot figure out what is wrong. I saw some examples of code using `glut` and it was working. But using `glfw` instead I cannot make it work. Here is the code I am using. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  float * computePixels(int iWidth, int iHeight) {
  float *pixels = new float[iWidth * iHeight * 4];
  int k = 0;
  for(int j = iHeight - 1; j >= 0 ; --j)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < iWidth; ++i)
    {
      pixels[k++] = static_cast<float>(i) / static_cast<float>(iWidth);
      pixels[k++] = static_cast<float>(j) / static_cast<float>(iHeight);
      pixels[k++] = 0.5f;
      pixels[k++] = 0.5f;
    }
  }
  return pixels;
}

int main () {
  // Initialize GLFW (error check removed on purpose for this post!)
  glfwInit();

  // configure GLFW
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x anti-aliasing
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // OpenGL 3.3
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); // OpenGL 3.3
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // for macos?
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); // new OpenGL

  int width = 1024;
  int height = 768;

  GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Tutorial 01", nullptr, nullptr);

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  // initialize GLEW
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  glewInit();

  float *pixels = computePixels(width, height);

  glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

  glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

  do
  {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glWindowPos2i(0, 0);

    glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  while(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);


  // Terminate GLFW
  glfwTerminate();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `glDrawPixels()` on a Core context?  It was removed from Core.  [GL 3.2 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec32.core.20091207.pdf), section E.2.2 "Removed Features", page 332, fourth bullet point.

Comment: I am no expert in OpenGL and so I did not know that. Thanks for pointing out the reason why my code is not working.

Answer (score 3):

`glDrawPixels` was removed from the core profile in version 3.2. It therefore is not available if you create an OpenGL context with the core profile.

Comment: Is there a way to create an OpenGL context with a different profile to make it work?